# Differential equation in optics

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

While playing with the eikonal equation (classical optics) I stumbled this differential equation :
$$
y y'' = k\left((y')^2 + 1\right)
$$
where $y=y(x)$ should be defined for $x>0$, $y>0$ and where $k\in \mathbb Z$. I don't know if there is a general solution $y(x)$ to that problem for a given $k$. What I know is that solving this for :

- $k=0$ is easy
- $k=1$ gives something like $y(x)=\cosh(x)$

**Question :** Is there a known solution for $k\in \mathbb Z \backslash \{0,1\}$ ?

---

**Remark 1 :** The general solution for $k=1$ is, as asked, $y(x)=y_0 \cosh((x-x_0)/y_0)$ for some constants $x_0,y_0$.

**Remark 2 :** The case $k=-1$ is solved below.

Comment: How did you solve the equation for $k=1$? Can you specify the exact form of the solution?

Comment: @stressed-out Infinite series would make a lot of trouble in this case, since the equation is non-linear.

Comment: @stressed-out It might be a good idea if you want an approximate solution, but in general you would rather prefer not to square an infinite series.

Comment: @stressed-out You can work out a relation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product. My point is that **sometimes** it is not useful trading one hard problem for another. However, the word sometimes is important - you can never know what direction will lead to the solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rewrite it as $$\frac{2y'y''}{(y')^2+1} = \frac{2ky'}{y}$$
Integrate to get $$\ln \left((y')^2+1\right) = 2k \ln y + c$$
So $$(y')^2+1 = C_1y^{2k}$$
Rearrange to get $$1=\frac{y'}{\sqrt{C_1y^{2k}-1}}$$
Integrate to get $$x+c_2 = \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{C_1y^{2k}-1}}$$
Substitute $y=\sec^{1/k}(t)/C_1^{1/2k}$ to get $$x+c_2 = \int \frac{1}{kC_1^{1/2k}}\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos^{1+1/k}(t)}\frac{1}{\tan(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{kC_1^{1/2k}}\int\frac{dt}{\cos^{1/k}(t)}$$

This last integral can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions (via [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F(cos(t))%5E(-1%2Fk)%20dt)), but this is about as far as you can go in general.

You can easily recover some special cases, e.g. $k=\pm 1$, from the last expression.  The next simplest case, $k=2$, yields an elliptic integral .  Elliptic integrals are well behaved special functions, so you might consider  this a very satisfactory solution.

You can't hope for an elementary solution for general k, because that would amount to finding an expression for special functions like elliptic integrals in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Yep that's brilliant.

Comment: @NAC I see from a comment of yours that you are interested in $k=1/2$.  In fact, you can get elementary solutions for $k=1/n$ for any integer $n\neq 0$.  This works out to just integrating a polynomial in $\cos(t)$ or $\sec(t)$.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't came with a full solution, but I can address the case $k=-1$. Our equation is

$$yy^{\prime\prime}=k\left(\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2+1\right)$$

$$\left(yy^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}-\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}=k\left(\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2+1\right)$$

$$\left(yy^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}=\left(k+1\right)\left(\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2+1\right)-1$$

Now if $k=-1$ the above equation simplifies tremendously to

$$\left(yy^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}=-1$$

$$yy^{\prime}=-x+\frac{A}{2}$$

$$\int y{\rm d}y=\int\left(-x+\frac{A}{2}\right){\rm d}x$$

$$\frac{y^2}{2}=-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{A}{2}x+\frac{B}{2}$$

$$y=\pm\sqrt{-x^{2}+Ax+B}$$

**EDIT:** If I continue with @stressed-out line of thought, for the general case we have to solve

$$yu\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}y}=k\left(u^{2}+1\right)$$

with $u=y^{\prime}$. This is far more manageable, as one can use seperation of variables

$$\int\frac{u{\rm d}u}{u^{2}+1}=\int\frac{k{\rm d}y}{y}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(u^{2}+1\right)=k\ln y+\tilde{A}$$

$$u^{2}+1=Ay^{2k}$$

with $A\equiv e^{2\tilde{A}}$. Further algebra yields

$$y^{\prime}=\pm\sqrt{Ay^{2k}-1}$$

$$\int\frac{{\rm d}y}{\sqrt{Ay^{2k}-1}}=\pm\int{\rm d}x$$

$$\int\frac{{\rm d}y}{\sqrt{Ay^{2k}-1}}=\pm x+B$$

The problem now is in solving this integral, which turns out to be quite complicated for most $k$'s. However, there is now another case that is easily solvable - $k=\frac{1}{2}$ (though not mentioned by the OP). Indeed for $k=\frac{1}{2}$

$$\int\frac{{\rm d}y}{\sqrt{Ay-1}}=\pm x+B$$

$$\frac{2}{A}\sqrt{Ay-1}=\pm x+B$$

$$Ay-1=\left(\pm\frac{A}{2}x+\frac{AB}{2}\right)^{2}$$

$$y=\frac{1}{A}\left(\left(\frac{A}{2}x+C\right)^{2}+1\right)$$

with $C\equiv \frac{AB}{2}$. Also the case $k=-\frac{1}{2}$ can be solved like this, but it is slightly more complicated to calculate the integral.

Comment: Yep ! Now $k=-1$ solved.

Comment: @NAC And we are left with only infinite more to solve!

Comment: @eranreches Meh, only a *countable* infinity. :)

Comment: @stressed-out Turns out your idea gives the same result as @Yly!

Comment: Yes that gives the same result. But the $k=1/2$ is welcomed for sure.

Comment: Shit... I was solving this on a piece of paper, you beat me to it by a few minutes. :| I had found out the way to make the first equation after the edit into a complete differential form and I was going further. Anyway, nice job. (+1) I'm glad to see that you didn't give up on my idea and it worked.

Comment: @stressed-out There's always next time ;) But you surely did a large portion of the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Again, just an observation: 
$$yy''-k(y')^2+k=0$$

Take $y'=u$
then $$y''=\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy}u$$
We will therefore obtain:
$$(y u)\frac{du}{dy}-k(u^2+1)=0$$

This idea was successfully followed and beautifully done by @eranreches. He/She has written it in his/her post and therefore, this post will be a community-wiki.

Comment: You should have $v^{\prime}-\frac{1}{2}u=k\left(u+1\right)$ and also in your last equation. Don't you?

Comment: What is $\varphi$? It must contain $y$, so your last equation is not $y$-free.

Comment: Because then you haven't fully eliminated $y$ from the equation, so you can't solve for $u$.

Comment: @eranreches: What about now? It seems to me that I have kind of reduced the difficulty of the problem. It seems more manageable to me now, but I'm not sure. Does it give you any idea?